# Webscraping table data with nested table as a cell under tr tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a table where some cells(td) in the rows(tr) have table tags again.

[url](https://www.ctdol.state.ct.us/progsupt/bussrvce/warnreports/warn2016.htm)

I am using the below code

```py
final_mydata = pd.DataFrame()

y_list = [2016, 2017, 2018]

for i in y_list:
    url = f"https://www.ctdol.state.ct.us/progsupt/bussrvce/warnreports/warn{i}.htm"
    
    print(i)
    
    page=requests.get(url)
    #print(url)
    #print(page)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    #soup
    table1 = soup.find('table', {'class':['MsoNormalTable','style15']})
    #headers=["WARN Date","Name of Affected Company","Location(s) of Layoffs","Number Affected Workers","Date(s) of Layoffs","Closing Yes/No","Date of Closing","Union Yes/No"]
    headers=["WARN Date","Name of Affected Company","Location(s) of Layoffs","Number Affected Workers","Date(s) of Layoffs","Closing Yes/No","Date of Closing","Union Yes/No"]
    #print(headers)
    mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

    #table1
    for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        row_data=j.find_all('td')[:8]
        row=[i.text for i in row_data]
        print(row)
        print(len(row),len(headers))
        if len(row)==len(headers):
            length=len(mydata)
            mydata.loc[length]=row
```

and it is giving me a response for those cells as

[image] refer row 33 and 35 where data is being repeated.

correct data should reflect as [image]

please help me to handle the nested `tbody`

Comment: You'll get a better response if you make it reproducible. We know base url but not the members of `y_list`, so we can't construct the full url. Supply at least one member.

Answer (score 0):

In the updated code below, you'll find a helper function to handle nested tables, if they're found within a `td`. The helper will simply convert rows to line breaks. Use this as a guide, as you'll likely need to handle the nested tables differently.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

def nested_table_to_text(table):
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    row_texts = []
    for row in rows:
        row_text = ' '.join([cell.text.strip() for cell in row.find_all('td')])
        row_texts.append(row_text)
    return '\n'.join(row_texts)

final_mydata = pd.DataFrame()
for i in y_list:
    url = url_base+str(i)+".htm"
    
    print(i)
    
    page=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    table1 = soup.find('table', {'class':['MsoNormalTable','style15']})
    headers=["WARN Date","Name of Affected Company","Location(s) of Layoffs","Number Affected Workers","Date(s) of Layoffs","Closing Yes/No","Date of Closing","Union Yes/No"]
    mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

    for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        row_data = j.find_all('td')[:8]
        row = []
        for cell in row_data:
            nested_table = cell.find('table')
            if nested_table:
                row.append(nested_table_to_text(nested_table))
            else:
                row.append(cell.text.strip())
        print(row)
        print(len(row),len(headers))
        if len(row) == len(headers):
            length = len(mydata)
            mydata.loc[length] = row
```

Did this solve your problem?

Comment: no, still the same duplicate data because the else condition will be traversing all the td anyway.